# Associating multiple images with a class object logic

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, logic

I'm looking to associate zero to three images to a class object when it is being created and I don't know the best way to do this.

Example: When a user creates a picture contest, they define their picture style with zero to three images. These are static images so they will never be updated.

The only way I can think of is to create a separate class called `stylePictures` and have three fields in the `Contest` saying "styleOne" "styleTwo" and "styleThree" which can be null. This seems like it is not the most efficient way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two separate classes. This way your feature can easily evolve into something that uses more pictures in the future.

```
class PictureContest(models.Model):
    # fields

class PictureStyle(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="upload/picture_style")
    picture_contest = models.ForeignKey("PictureContest")
```

To get all the picture styles associated with the one picture contest.

First you must isolate the picture contest that you want.

```
pc = PictureContest.objects.filter(id=2) # find your picture contest
```

Then filter the picture styles that have `pc.id` as a field value.

```
pic_styles = PictureStyle.objects.filter(picture_contest__id=pc.id)
```

Comment: This is the route I was thinking, but then in PictureContest what fields would you add to say if a particular PictureStyle instance was chosen? I need to have zero to three PictureStyle objects associated with one PictureContest object